# bootstrap not following column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

SO i m trying to add input forms with different column width ..
Below is my code:

`<

```
div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-10">
   <div class="form-group form-inline col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <input type="text" name="cw" id="inputammino" value="A">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-inline col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <input type="text" name="cw2" id="inputcusti" value="42.010565">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-inline col-md-2 col-lg-4">
     <input type="text" name="cw3" id="amiaci" value="K">
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

`

[image: <code>bootstrap form</code>]

But instead of adding more column width to first column its adding it to last..What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using right now ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3

Comment: Is that your complete html ?

Comment: no its pretty big ...

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) and I have formatted your HTML as below by using [BootStrap 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-inline) Documentation and its working fine for me.

```
<div class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="cw" id="inputammino" value="A">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="cw2" id="inputcusti" value="42.010565">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
       <input type="text" name="cw3" id="amiaci" value="K">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```